# How can a referenced value stay in memory when the original variable that holds it has a new referenced value?

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

I found this awfully old comment in the [PHP docs comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php#72945), but can't get my mind around it why it outputs "hihaha" and not "eita" in the first example. `$a` is changed and I'd assume that `"hihaha"` is removed for good. If not, then why is it so that if the change is to `null` or assigning a copy of another variable, then the `"hihaha"` IS removed for good?

```
// 1. example
$a = "hihaha";
$b = &$a;
$c = "eita";
$a = &$c; // why doesn't this purge "hihaha" from existence?
echo $b; // shows "hihaha" WHY?

// 2. example
$a = "hihaha";
$b = &$a;
$a = null;
echo $b; // shows nothing (both are set to null)

// 3. example
$a = "hihaha";
$b = &$a;
$c = "eita";
$a = $c;
echo $b; // shows "eita"
```

Is this a "good way" towards the circular references problem?

Comment: Because you've copied the reference. Because you've stomped on the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with `$a = "hihaha";`, when you do `$b = &$a;`, `$b` is *not* referencing `$a`. It is referencing the *content* of `$a`. As it says in [PHP: What References Do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):

> $a and $b are completely equal here. $a is not pointing to $b or vice versa. $a and $b are pointing to the same place.

Then after `$c = "eita";`, when you do `$a = &$c;`, `$a` is now referencing the content of `$c` ("eita").

This does not affect `$b` at all. `$b` is still referencing the original content of `$a` ("hihaha"). Pointing `$a` at something else does not change that.

In case you have a more mspaint learning style, here is a visual aid representing the first four statements of example 1:

[image]

---

In the second example, `$a` and `$b` are still pointing at the same content when `$a` is set to `null`, so `$b` is now referencing `null` as well. Visually:

[image]

Comment: Can't beat an mspaint explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Think of a variable as pointing to a reference - to break down Example 1...

---

**1**

```
$a = "hihaha";
```

`$a` points to the reference for the string `hihaha`, lets call it *R1*

---

**2**

```
$b =& $a;
```

Here we are saying, point `$b` to the same reference as`$a` (*R1*)

---

**3**

```
$c = "eita";
```

`$c` points to the reference for the string `eita`, lets call it *R2*

---

**4**

```
$a =& $c;
```

Now we say, point `$a` to the same reference as `$c` (`$b` still points to *R1*)

At this stage,
`$a` and `$c` point to *R2*,
`$b` points to *R1*
- should be easy to guess what happens next!

---

**5**

```
echo $b; // hihaha
```

We now know that `echo`ing `$b` will output *R1*!

---

Hope that helps!

Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php